# Numpy array indexing syntax

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning `numpy` newly and confused about syntax used in indexing of arrays. For example:

```
arr[2, 3]
```

This means element at intersection of 3nd row and 4th column. What confuses me separation of different indices by comma inside square brackets (like in function arguments). Doing so with python lists is not valid:

```
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
l[1, 1]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

So, if this not a valid python syntax, how numpy arrays work?

Comment: Problem is that `l` is a list, not a numpy array

Comment: `arr[2,3]` passes a tuple `(2,3)` to the `arr.__getitem__` method.  For arrays, that method can handle tuples.  The list indexing method cannot, and raises the `TypeError` (not a SyntaxError).  Different classes have different indexing methods.  Also, it's the comma that creates the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use Colon ':' instead of commas ','.
In slicing or indexing is done using colon ':'

In your above example,
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

->l[0] is [1,2] and -> l[1] is [3,4]

Read further documentation for better understanding.
Thank You

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. please read carefully, since my question is about totally different thing

Answer (score 0):

In your given example, you're comparing a `numpy` array to a list of lists. The main difference between the two is that a `numpy` array is predictable in terms of shape, data type of its elements, and so on, while a list can contain an arbitrary combination of any other python objects (lists, tuples, strings, etc.)

Take this as an example, say you create a `numpy` array like so:

```py
arr = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]])
```

Here, the shape of `arr` is known right after instantiation "`arr.shape` returns (3,2)", so you can easily index the array with only a comma separated square bracket. On the other hand, take the list example:

```py
l = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
l[0]   # This returns the list [0, 1]
l[0].append("HELLO")
l[0]   # This returns the list [0, 1, "HELLO"]
```

A list is very unpredictable, as there's no way to know what each list element will return to you. So, the way we index a specific element in a list of lists is by using 2 square brackets "e.g. `l[0][0]`"

What if we created a non-uniform `numpy` array? Well, you get a similar behaviour to a list of lists:

```py
arr = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4]])   # Here, you get a Warning! 
print(arr)  # Returns: array([list([0, 1]), list([2, 3]), list([4])], dtype=object)
```

In this case, you can't index the `numpy` array using [0, 0]. Instead, you have to use two square brackets, just like a list of lists

You can also check the documentation of [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) for more info.